# python - attribute x is a property object which provides interface to this private variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand property in depth following this article.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    def set_temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value

    temperature = property(get_temperature,set_temperature)
```

One thing that intrigues me is how the `_temperature` and `temperature` variable works.

As per this article,

> The attribute temperature is a property object which provides
>   interface to this private variable.

How does this interface functionality provided in python?

```
c = Celsius()
print(dir(c))
```

When I print the dir(c) it shows the following -

```
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'get_temperature', 'set_temperature', 'temperature', 'to_fahrenheit']
```

The _temperature variable is hidden.

When I inherit the `Celsius(object)` from object class that shows a different result -

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_temperature', 'get_temperature', 'set_temperature', 'temperature', 'to_fahrenheit']
```

Comment: Properties only work with new-style classes, which in Python 2 are those that *expicitly* inherit from `object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`property(get_temperature,set_temperature)` is a *descriptor*, which means that when you access it on an instance, you get custom behaviour.  A descriptor is an object that provides `__get__()`, `__set__()` and / or `__del__()` methods.

You can find details about descriptors here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

`property` objects in particular allow you to supply `get` and `set` methods that will be called when you try to access or set the object.

The modern idiom is to use decorator syntax for this:

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value
```

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's primary issue, which is that they are using Python 2 and old-style classes don't support the descriptor protocol.

Comment: @chepner I felt like the core of the post was "How does this interface functionality provided in python?"